# Uncaught Error in autocomplete select item

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am getting autocomplete item list from javascript autocomplete but when I select that autocomplete item list at that time it shows the error i.e. **Uncaught TypeError: n.item is undefined**

Here is my code,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <nop-label asp-for="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">                    
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Name)
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Product")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val) {
                        return {
                            label: val.Name,
                            value: val.Name
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (ui) {
            $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the controller**

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term = "")
{
    var objCustomerlist = (from product in _productMasterRepository.Table
                           where product.Name.StartsWith(term)
                           select new
                           {
                               Name = product.Name,
                               ID = product.Name
                           }).ToList();
    return Json(objCustomerlist);
}
```

Comment: what is your autocomplete plugin? if you are getting results ok from server side, then the issue is on client side, knowing the right plugin will be helpful to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select signature is incorrect:

```
select: function (ui) {
        $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
    }
```

Change it into:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
         $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
     }
```

And that should work fine.